How to monkey patch `__init__` in a third party module?
I'm trying to monkey patch the __init__ method of a third party module (smbprotocol).
Specifically, the SMBDirectoryIO#_init__ which inherits from SMBRawIO#__init__ (here)
I want to add "a" to the mode with which the file is opened, because currently listdir only calls SMBDirectoryIO with mode="r" which isn't enough for my needs (see here)
I've tried various takes on the following approach, but the code doesn't seem to ever be hit

import smbclient._io


class SMBDirectoryIOPatched(smbclient._io.SMBDirectoryIO):
    def __init__(self, path, mode, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(path, mode + "a", *args, **kwargs)


smbclient._io.SMBDirectoryIO = SMBDirectoryIOPatched


Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thanks

You might want to submit a patch to the original project. Sounds like a reasonable feature that's easy to implement.

_io makes me think that the module is likely implemented in C. You won't get any mileage monkey patching that.

Also, how do you know it's __init__ and not __new__ that needs patching?

Also, given the above, why don't you just use the class you want directly?

The file containing listdir() (_os.py) has probably already imported SMBDirectoryIO before your monkey patch, so it doesn't see your replaced class.  You could either store the new class in that module as well, or you could directly assign your function to SMBDirectoryIO.__init__ (rather than defining a new class at all).

Patching the class inside _os module as well did the trick. Thanks @jasonharper
